# How to get Responsiveness for the mobile approach for the code using media queries

Tags: reactjs

https://github.com/PUNNU96/covid-19-.git
Check with the Home page where am unable to get the responsiveness for mobile approach. i tried using media queries but unable to get it please resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Bottstrap css framework by installing the official npm package

```
npm i bootstrap
```

And  if you are the adventurous type personality, you can use Flexbox in your CSS
Refer this Flexbox cheatsheet
[Flexbox CheatSheet Reference](https://codepen.io/enxaneta/full/adLPwv/)